# Applications of cohomology to probability and statistics

Tags: pr.probability, soft-question, homological-algebra, st.statistics, cohomology

Are there interesting/useful applications of cohomology (and homological algebra in general) to probability and statistics, or information theory?

By "interesting/useful", I mean "not merely descriptive", that is, they can actually say something new and not just formalize well known concepts.

For example, I have recently found [this paper](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-30232-9_4), which addresses dually flat manifolds (and so, indirectly, information geometry).

Any other examples I have missed?

Thanks!

(Feel free to edit tags appropriately.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a very nice interpretation of entropy as a cohomology class by Baudot and Bennequin which you can read about [HERE](http://djafari.free.fr/MaxEnt2014/papers/97_paper.pdf).

In general, I strongly believe that there is an underlying topological content to parts of information theory- as there is information geometry, there will be information topology.

Comment: Interesting. I have the same feeling! But no real ideas so far...thanks!

Comment: Well, to plug my own work (which doesn't answer your question but which might interest you anyway), Avishy Carmi and I have a different approach to the topic of information topology, not via (co)homology, but rather via quandle-coloured tangles. Some preliminary findings are here: http://arxiv.org/abs/1409.5505

Comment: Wow thank you. I'll take a look at it right now!

Answer (score 5):

[Persistent homology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_homology) seems to be quite fashionable right now. I've also found [this blog entry](http://ldtopology.wordpress.com/2015/01/05/topology-of-musical-data/) by Ryan Budney quite amusing.

Comment: Interesting! (Particularly since I am a musician too!)